# Is $\frac{(|x| - x^2)}{\sin x}$ an odd function, if it is odd, how do I prove that?

Tags: even-and-odd-functions

This is the function:

$$f(x)=\frac{|x|-x^{2}}{\sin x}$$

I am not understanding where to go from the second line:

$$\begin{array}{l}
f(-x) & =\displaystyle\frac{|-x|-(-x)^{2}}{\sin(-x)}\\
\displaystyle & =\displaystyle\frac{|-x|-(-x)^{2}}{-\sin x}
\end{array}$$

How do make this equal $-f(x)$? Or is it neither odd nor even?

Comment: It is odd since $|x|$ and $x^2$ are even and $\sin$ is odd

Comment: $|-x|=|x|,(-x)^2=x^2$, since both are even functions. But $\sin(-x)=-\sin x$ since $\sin x$ is odd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have $|-x|=|x|$ and $(-x)^2=x^2$.

Answer (score 0):

You have
$$\begin{array}{l}
f(- x) =\frac{|x|\ -\ ( x)^{2}}{-sin( x)}\\
\end{array}$$
and this is $-f(x)$ so $f$ is odd.